# Encoding problem with accents and inputenc package

Tags: pdftex, packages, input, accents, input-encodings

I have this problem, it seems I'm doing something wrong while writing letters with accents like `è`, on that line the compiler says: `package inputenc Error: unicode char \u8:èun not set up for use`. This happens when I use my LaTeX editor, compiling the same code with an R sweave file on Rstudio it works normally and I got my accents on letters.

The code used is:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside,openright]{book} %oneside versione segreteria
\usepackage[a4paper,top=2cm,bottom=2cm,left=3cm,right=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,italian]{babel}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
%\uspackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

%________________________________________________________________

\frontmatter

%space for abstract

\pagestyle{plain}
\tableofcontents

%_______________________________________________


\mainmatter

\pagestyle{plain} 

%Primo Capitolo
%\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduzione}

\chapter*{Introduzione}

L'accrescimento è  


\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you sure the file is UTF-8 encoded?

Comment: what do you mean? sorry i'm not an expert on LaTeX. It's that i always put that kind of preamble and it always worked.

Comment: What editor are you using?

Comment: TeXShop, always used it

Comment: If you haven't changed its preferences, TeXShop doesn't save in UTF-8. Remember to add `% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode` at the start of your files. Do it and save the file; close and reopen it, then try running LaTeX on it.

Comment: Thank you it worked. I just don't get why it always worked without that so far

Comment: The most recent versions of TeXShop have a document about encoding under the Help menu: Help->File Encoding and TeXShop.

Comment: For others getting this error using TeXstudio (which has a 'Default Font Encoding' setting in the Preferences menu and has 'Automatic Encoding Detection') I found that some 'é' characters were actually a combination of `chr(101)` (`'e'`) and `chr(769)` (`'́'`) so I fixed it by replacing them with `é` `chr(233)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Very likely your file ended up not being saved as UTF-8.

If you didn't change the default settings in the preferences, TeXShop saves files as Latin-1 (older versions use MacRoman).

Remember to add

```
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
```

at the start of your files. Do it and save the file; close and reopen it, then try running LaTeX on it.

In any case, it's better if you also go to the preferences and change the default encoding to UTF-8.

Comment: Adding the "magic comment" `% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode` at the top the file is fantastic. Thank you!